# delete Row in a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

delete rows based on the duplicate column in a CSV file
for eg., CSV file contains.

```
CampaignCode | CellCode     | StartDate   | Phone| Account
C000001413   |  A000363363  |  20170601   | 4167292999  | 999999999
C000001414   |  A000363364  |  20170601   | 4167292999  | 999999999
```

Here I want to delete the complete row based on the `Phone` column duplicates.
expected output is:
    CampaignCode | CellCode     | StartDate   | Phone       | Account
    C000001413   |  A000363363  |  20170601   | 4167292999  | 999999999

Comment: What did you try to solve it yourself? This site is not for getting readymade answers. Please share your attempts and then seek help.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Hi All,  I am new to this site, sure I will take care of all the suggestions going forward.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for you is read the csv file line by line, put each line into a list and check duplicate at column you want => write down the list of new line into current file. Sample code for you (I'm using comma to seperate instead of |)

```
public class CSVReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String csvFile = "csv.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean isDuplicate = false;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            isDuplicate = false;
            String[] object = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            for (String l : lines) {
                if (l.contains(object[3])) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isDuplicate) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        }
        for (String newL : lines) {
            System.out.println(newL);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have writing code, then just test it. What problem make you can not test it?

Comment: tested locally and its working fine.